# How to edit managed package static resource in Subscriber Org

Tags: lightning-web-components, managed-package

In managed package one zipped static resource is there which is being used in LWC component to show the logo, picture and load js, css etc etc.

As we know, we can't edit/upload the managed package's static resource in the subscriber organization, but the customer has a requirement to edit and upload the static resource. We can't create a new static resource on the subscriber end because we are using the name of the managed package's static resource in the managed package's LWC code.

***What is the workaround to resolve this scenario?***

**Sample code that used in LWC component**

```
import HOMEIMAGES from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/StaticResource_Home';
export default class ActionItems extends LightningElement {
    labels = {resources};
    newCampaignBtnIcon = HOMEIMAGES + this.labels.resources.MEP_ActionItem_NewCampaignBtnIcon_Path;
    reviewReportsBtnIcon = HOMEIMAGES + this.labels.resources.MEP_ActionItem_ReviewReportsBtnIcon_Path;
```

Comment: You need a change to be made to the managed package to either 1) allow an alternative static resource to be used via configuration or 2) provide an API (could be another LWC, a `global` apex method or something else) that allows the static resource to be replaced. Without something in the managed package namespace supporting what you want to do, it's simply not possible. There's a chance you might, in the short term, perform a subscriber login to the org and update the static resource on the given org, but any upgrade will overwrite it (even if this is possible).